# Auto stretching of adjacent column size when the current column has a lot of elements in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have two columns in a table in ASP.NET page. In the first column I have a Grid View that gets populated from the database using the SQLDATASOURCE.

In the second column I have certain textboxes and checkboxes and buttons.

When I run the page in a browser, the data gets populated in the gridview which actually disturbs the alignment of the adjacent column that contains the textboxes and the checkboxes.

These textboxes and checkboxes that are supposed to be visible at the top of the column are now visible at the center because the gridview data populated disturbs it.

Please help with this as I want these textboxes and checkboxes in the second column to be visible at the top of the column.

Comment: show your page markup please. I also suggest to do not put a grid side by side with other controls and possibly to avoid to nest a GridView in a table. It is arguable I know, but also depends on how many columns you have in your GridView, if you want to support smaller screens and tablets and so on. I would simply have the GridView full with in the page and other controls either before or after but not side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vertical alignment of your second table cell:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top">xx</td>
```

The default value is "middle" which is why your content gets pushed to the middle as the vertical height of the table cell gets taller than your content.